# Regex and non-technical users

Tags: regex, user-input, business-rules

**Given that:**

- You have some Key-Value data that can be modified
- Modification is done via by applying filters to the data. Filters that control what gets changed are created by non-technical people
- The filters are setup using regular expressions. An example of a rule described as part of a filter may be "If a key matches some regex, replace value with some other value"

**How would you:**

If filters are to be produced by business people, who can't create regular expressions, in what form would you have them submit their input that would be easily translated to regex?

Comment: Unless you have a VERY SPECIFIC set of filters that can translate easily enough to regexes on the back end, I doubt this will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Agent Ransack](http://mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home) contains a GUI editor for creating regular expressions from plain English, I would suggest taking a look at that and implementing your own variation of it.

See the screenshot for an example:[image: taken from app website]

Answer (score 2):

If it works, I would go for "wildcard only" support - ie the asterisk `*` is the only special character allowed and you translate that to the regex `.*?` in code.

Most non-technical people can grasp `*` meaning "anything".